# When to use shellout?

Tags: chef-infra, mixlib-shellout

When is it appropriate to use shellout in a recipe instead of bash blocks or execute? I'm inclining to using it by default for all outside calls, because of its logging, but the verbosity of the command are a disadvantage.

Comment: I'm thinking the intention was design something to replace execute/bash blocks. I personally haven't used it but this has a little more info aside from the git docs: http://www.foodcritic.io/#FC048

Comment: That FC rule says to prefer shellout to standard ruby \`\` or %x. It doesn't say anything about using native resources versus shellout. They have different purposes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Use Shellout

When you need to get the **result** of the command to use elsewhere

### Use `script` and children

When you want Chef to execute the code for you.

Shellout is not a replacement to `script`/`execute` blocks. They also execute at different times during the Chef Client run. Shellout is a Ruby thing, whereas `script`/`execute` are Chef resources like `template`. There is a lot of safety and cross-platform support wrapped in these resources that you won't get with Shellout.